# google analytics tracking events from iframed page

Tags: events, iframe, google-analytics, tracking

I'm having this problem in tracking GA events from iFramed page.
It is tracking but it's clearly tracking wrongly.

Unique events data seems to be OK, Total events definitely not OK... It shows that on avg. one visit makes 80 events, which I know is not right.

I didn't put any flags into GA tracking code.
It's just simple one domain tracking code.

So, I put tracking code into  of my page and this page is iFramed into another.
It's a simple interactive banner where Click events are tracked.

I'm guessing I'm missing something in GA tracking code to make it work properly.

Does anyone had this problem, what am I missing to get Events tracked properly?